# Kivy with Asyncio Exits application

Tags: python, kivy, python-asyncio

This is a very hard issue and it is client server so I'm sorry for just the client code.  Perhaps someone can give me some direction on this though.

First, in the client there is an asyncio function called listen.  This function reads input that comes in from the server and preforms an action.  The current issue is when an RPGMessage message comes in as a non-popup it crashes the application with no error, just "leaving application in process.".  Perhaps I can extend debug some how in Kivy?

```
async def listen():
    while True:
        for message in CLIENT.get_reader_queue():
            message = loads(message, cls=CustomJSONDecoder)

            if isinstance(message, RPGMenu):
                CLIENT_SCREEN.set_current_menu(message)
                CLIENT_SCREEN.refresh()

                if message.description is not None:
                    CLIENT_SCREEN.add_text_item(message.description)
            elif isinstance(message, RPGMessage):
                if message.popup is False:
                    CLIENT_SCREEN.add_text_item(message.text, message.font) <-- THIS IS THE LINE IT WILL TRIGGER.
                else:
                    layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
                    layout.add_widget(Label(text=message.text))
                    button = Button(text='close', size_hint_y=0.25)
                    layout.add_widget(button)

                    popup = Popup(title='Server Message',
                                  content=layout,
                                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400), auto_dismiss=False)
                    button.bind(on_press=popup.dismiss)

                    popup.open()
            elif isinstance(message, RPGMedia):
                PopupWindow(message.name, message.text, message.image)
            elif isinstance(message, RPGResultFailure):
                PopupWindow(message.name, message.description)
            elif isinstance(message, RPGResult):
                CLIENT.result = message

        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
```

Anyhow the above calls CLIENT_SCREEN.add_text_item() which is shown below;

```
def add_text_item(self, text: str, font: str=None):
    text_input = Label()
    text_input.padding_x = 10
    text_input.size_hint_y = None
    text_input.markup = True
    text_input.text = text + '\n'
    if font is not None:
        text_input.font_name = font
    text_input.font_size = '20sp'

    text_input.bind(size=self.on_size_text_label)
    self.text_grid_layout.add_widget(text_input)
    self.text_scroll_view.scroll_to(text_input)
    text_input.bind(on_ref_press=self.on_reference_press)
```

Also here is my loops that I'm starting;

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    CLIENT = Client('127.0.0.1', 9000, loop)

    executer = ThreadPoolExecutor(2)

    # asyncio.ensure_future(test())
    # asyncio.ensure_future(console())
    asyncio.ensure_future(listen())

    # MyApp().run()
    loop.run_in_executor(executer, MyApp().run)
    loop.run_forever()
```

When I run the debugger it adds the text item and then goes back to the asyncio loop but kivy dies.

Any thoughts?  I know this is a difficult issue to convey.

Thanks.

Update;
I have tried to increase debug with - but is no help for this issue;

```
Config.set('kivy', 'log_level', 'debug')
```

Comment: It's interesting, the current callback comes from a text REF callback, if the same function comes from a button it works fine.  I'm at a loss.  I have also tried debug mode in python to show the trace back but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to this.

In order for me to mix Kivy and asyncio I was able to launch my asyncio loop in a thread attached to the Kivy App.  This seems to cleanup the whole situation.

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        from kivy.core.window import Window

        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.transition = NoTransition()

        login_screen = LoginScreen(name='login')
        client_screen = ClientScreen(name='client')

        sm.add_widget(login_screen)
        sm.add_widget(client_screen)

        sm.current = 'login'

        Window.size = (300, 120)
        self.title = 'xNemesis Client V0'

        asyncio.ensure_future(listen(client_screen))

        x = threading.Thread(target=loop.run_forever)
        x.start()

        return sm
```

So the application is built, and just at the end I start the thread for the asyncio loop.  That way I'm not using global variables as well, which I think wasn't liked.